# Have to take input from 'aspell' and manipulate it to take user input

Tags: bash, shell, unix

so I am having issues with this shell script and how to implement what I want to. I'm reading in from a file and spellchecking it using:

```
cat $1|aspell list
```

this lists the misspelled words but how would I separate it so that i get an output like:

```
'agle' is mispelled. Press "Enter" to keep
this spelling, or type a correction here: angle

'objekt' is mispelled. Press "Enter" to keep
this spelling, or type a correction here: object
```

I was trying to store misspelled words into variables but that seems like the wrong way to do things. If anyone can point me in the right direction that would be great.

EDIT: someone requested my full script so far:

```
#!/bin/bash
mispelledWords=$(cat $1|aspell list)
ARRAY=( $mispelledWords )
for i in "${ARRAY[@]}"
do 
        echo $i[1]
done
```

Comment: Consider posting your script so someone can point you in that right direction.

Comment: Posted full script

Answer (score 0):

You can store your list into an array like

```
 myvar=($(cat $1 | aspell list))
```

Then access each element like

```
${myvar[0]}
${myvar[1]}
```

And number of elements in array using

```
${#myvar[@]}
```

[EDIT] Here is an example script

```
#!/bin/bash
ARR=$(cat $1|aspell list)
for i in $ARR
do
        echo $i
done
```